# get the number of row reference to a particular column ID

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I would like to get the number of row reference to a particular column (let say ID) of a table set in Oracle DB
my code is

```
String selectTableRowsSQL4 = "SELECT row "
+ "FROM contract_type_info"
+ "WHERE ID = ?";              
preparedStatementSelect = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectTableRowsSQL4);
preparedStatementSelect.setInt(1, 5);
preparedStatementSelect.getResultSet().getRow();
System.out.println("Row: " + preparedStatementSelect.getResultSet().getRow());
```

when I run the above code my result is zero (0)!

In fact I am trying to find out in which row the ID=5 is?

Comment: What do you get when you execute your select manually in some SQL client?

Comment: Why you call `preparedStatementSelect.getResultSet().getRow();` two times?

Comment: zero (0) !!! ? Do you mean the row count ?

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
select count(row)
from countract_type_info
where id = 10
```

In your case

```
String selectTableRowsSQL4 = "SELECT count(row) "
+ "FROM contract_type_info"
+ "WHERE ID = ?";
```

Comment: the SELECT of "count" provides info on how many elements of ID referring to the column (WHERE) are within the table (FROM).

Comment: I am trying to access the particular element within the table using java rs.absolute(NoOfRow) command. In fact I am trying to know the NoOfRow (Number of Row) by knowing where (which row) a particular element within the table is placed

Answer (score 0):

Something like below ?? and also you never executed your query in the first place. youhave to execute the query using [**PreparedStatement.executeQuery()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) which returns a `ResultSet object`.

```
preparedStatementSelect = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectTableRowsSQL4);
preparedStatementSelect.setInt(1, 5);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println("Row: " + rs.getRow());
}
```

Comment: I am trying to access the particular element within the table using java rs.absolute(NoOfRow) command. In fact I am trying to know the NoOfRow (Number of Row) by knowing where (which row) a particular element within the table is placed ....

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advices.

Comment: your code suggestion results all rows; I am looking the row that contains a particular element in the table!

Answer (score 0):

Are you [executing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29) that prepared statement ?

> The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of
>   the first result. You must then use the methods getResultSet or
>   getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to
>   any subsequent result(s).

You need to execute this prior to getting the result set. See the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) for more info.

You have to use [the SQL count() method](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) to get the number of rows, *or* (less efficient) iterate through the result set and count using `ResultSet.next()`